# Calculate angle between two Latitude/Longitude points

Tags: math, google-maps

Is there a way to calculate angle between two  Latitude/Longitude points?

What I am trying to achieve is to know where the user is heading. For example, user is heading North, South,.... South-East, etc.

But I have only two points (Lng/Ltd)

Thx

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is bearing not angle.  the bearing is the direction of travel as displayed on a compass when moving from point a to point b.

Answer (score 62):

using [this](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)  referance to calculate Angle:

```
private double angleFromCoordinate(double lat1, double long1, double lat2,
        double long2) {

    double dLon = (long2 - long1);

    double y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
    double x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)
            * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);

    double brng = Math.atan2(y, x);

    brng = Math.toDegrees(brng);
    brng = (brng + 360) % 360;
    brng = 360 - brng; // count degrees counter-clockwise - remove to make clockwise

    return brng;
}
```

Comment: Works for me, without the brng = 360 - brng;

Comment: As latitude and longitude are usually expressed in degrees, do not forget to convert them to radians before using this function.

Comment: cos(lat2) can be refactored out, leaving tan(lat2) instead of sin(lat2)

Comment: @Michael: could you elaborate on that? Do you mean we can simply replace all occurrences of cos(lat2) by 1 and sin(lat2) by tan(lat2)?

Comment: Does not work for me : angleFromCoordinate(Math.toRadians(0f), Math.toRadians(0f), Math.toRadians(0f), Math.toRadians(45f)); results in 270, which is wrong! Any help ?

Comment: This site to check your answer: https://www.igismap.com/map-tool/bearing-angle

Answer (score 19):

You just can use the google maps computeHeading:

```
var point1 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lng1);
var point2 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lng2);
var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(point1,point2);
```

Comment: Using Google Maps for simple trig seems a bit overkill.

Comment: Not applicable for onboard systems that don't access Google Maps (Arduino project for instance)

Comment: What do you have to install to use this in your script?

Answer (score 14):

The general formula for calculating the angle(bearing) between two points is as follows:

```
θ = atan2(sin(Δlong)*cos(lat2), cos(lat1)*sin(lat2) − sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(Δlong))
```

Note that the angle(θ) should be converted to radians before using this formula and 
Δlong = long2 - long1.

atan2 is a common function found in almost all programming languages (mostly in the Math package/library). Usually there are also functions for conversion between degrees and radians(also in the Math package/library).

Remember that atan2 returns values in the range of -π ... +π, to convert the result to a compass bearing, you need to multiply θ by 180/π then use (θ+360) % 360, where % is modulus division operation returning the remainder of the division.

The following link is a good resource for formulas involving latitudes and longitudes. They also provide Javascript implementation of their formulas. In fact, this answer is based on the information from this page:

http://www.yourhomenow.com/house/haversine.html

Comment: cos(lat2) can be refactored out, leaving tan(lat2) instead of sin(lat2)

Comment: Link is dead as of 12-2019

Answer (score 9):

Based on Nayanesh Gupte's answer, here is a Python implementation of how to calculate the angle between two points defined by their latitudes and longitudes if anyone needs it:

```
import math

def angleFromCoordinate(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):
    dLon = (long2 - long1)

    y = math.sin(dLon) * math.cos(lat2)
    x = math.cos(lat1) * math.sin(lat2) - math.sin(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.cos(dLon)

    brng = math.atan2(y, x)

    brng = math.degrees(brng)
    brng = (brng + 360) % 360
    brng = 360 - brng # count degrees clockwise - remove to make counter-clockwise

    return brng
```

Where an angle of 0 degrees indicates a northward heading.

Comment: Note this requires `import math`

Comment: mmm, I ve tried it and checked it with https://www.igismap.com/map-tool/bearing-angle and it does not give the same or near values...

Comment: try without 'brng = 360 - brng ' it gives value as per https://www.igismap.com/map-tool/bearing-angle ![test](https://i.imgur.com/fxSF4WM.png)

Answer (score 7):

In The Javascript, I create a function name `angleFromCoordinate` in which i pass two lat/lng. This function will return angel between that two lat/lng

```
function angleFromCoordinate(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
    var p1 = {
        x: lat1,
        y: lon1
    };

    var p2 = {
        x: lat2,
        y: lon2
    };
    // angle in radians
    var angleRadians = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
    // angle in degrees
    var angleDeg = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
    console.log(angleDeg);
    return angleDeg;
}
```

Working Code Snippet

```js
function angleFromCoordinate(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
    var p1 = {
        x: lat1,
        y: lon1
    };

    var p2 = {
        x: lat2,
        y: lon2
    };
    // angle in radians
    var angleRadians = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
    // angle in degrees
    var angleDeg = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;

    document.getElementById('rotation').innerHTML ="Rotation : "+ angleDeg;
    return angleDeg;
    
}
     angleFromCoordinate(37.330604,-122.028947,37.3322109,-122.0329665);
```

```html
<html>
<p id="rotation">Rotation : </p>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure your answer is correct because for me it is showing some other answer. For same coordinates the function which I have made is giving me 63.52 something and your answer is -68.20. Is it correct ?

Comment: For better assistance, can u provide both lat lng ? 
@YashasviBhatt

Answer (score 4):

Sample javascript code if the distance between points is less -

```
brng = Math.atan2(newLat - oldLat, newLong - oldLong);
brng = brng * (180 / Math.PI);
brng = (brng + 360) % 360;
brng = 360 - brng;
```

Comment: hi @poorva, could you explain what you mean by if the distance between points is less -?

Answer (score 4):

If your are using google maps(Android), there is an easy way - Use SphericalUtil

```
double angle = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(fromLatLng, toLatLng);
```

Consider we have 2 points and its lat and lng
Then create its Latlng object

```
LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latValue, lngValue);
```

After getting Latlng of 2 points, use sperical util to get angle

```
//import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil;
double sphericalValue = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(latLng1, latLng2);
```

SpericalValue is the angle.
Consider you have a car icon and turn it accordingly to the direction its going.  Here its from latLng1 to latLng2 then

```
Bitmap vehiclePin = rotateIconBitmap(sphericalValue);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().anchor(0.5f, 0.5f).position(latLng2))
               .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(vehiclePin));
```

use the method below to rotate

```
    Bitmap rotateIconBitmap(double angle) {
       Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
                                          R.drawable.ic_vehicle_say_car);
       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       matrix.postRotate((float) angle);
       return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, 
                    source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
```

[image]

Easy way to achieve uber like rotated icons

Note:- You may have to add an offset of say 90 degree if the marker icon is not pointed to zero degree

The android sphericalutil is open source, refer it if you are using java, you can make use of it.

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java

Comment: angle may be in radian, go inside the class and check.

Answer (score 3):

To provide heading you have to compute bearing.

To understand bearing read [this article](https://revisionmaths.com/gcse-maths-revision/trigonometry/bearings).

According to this [article (section bearing)](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) the formula is :

```
θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )
where φ1, λ1 is the start point, 
      φ2, λ2 the end point,
      Δλ is the difference in longitude`
```

Here's a sample on how to compute the angle (in degrees) between two points expressed in Lat/Lon. (done in C#)

Let's say `Point` is a simple class with two `double` attributes X (for longitude) and Y (for latitude).

```
public double ComputeBearing(Point start,Point end)
{
     var φ1 = start.Y; //latitude 1
     var λ1 = start.X; //longitude 1
     var φ2 = end.Y; //latitude 2
     var λ2 = end.X; //longitude 2

     var y = Math.Sin(this.degreeToRadian(λ2 - λ1)) * Math.Cos(this.degreeToRadian(φ2));
     var x = Math.Cos(this.degreeToRadian(φ1)) * Math.Sin(this.degreeToRadian(φ2)) - Math.Sin(this.degreeToRadian(φ1)) * Math.Cos(this.degreeToRadian(φ2)) * Math.Cos(this.degreeToRadian(λ2 - λ1));

     var θ = Math.Atan2(y, x);
     θ = this.radianToDegree(θ);

     return θ;
}
```

Using the following methods :

```
public double degreeToRadian(double angle)
{
    return Math.PI * angle / 180.0;
}

public double radianToDegree(double angle)
{
    return angle * (180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```

By using `ComputeBearing` you will easily get an angle expressed in degrees easily usable as heading

Answer (score 2):

```
function calculateAngle(lat, lng) {
    var checkLengthInterval = 2;

    // Calculate Angle
    //If ObjFeed == [] add first object.
    if (ObjFeed.length == 0) {
        ObjFeed.push({ 'lat': lat, 'lng': lng });
    } else {
        // Get last object from list to calculate angle betwn last and latest.
        var tempNode = ObjFeed[ObjFeed.length - 1];
        // If last lat and lng is same as current it will always return 0 angle.so only push lat lng in obj which is diff than last one.
        if (!(tempNode.lat == lat && tempNode.lng == lng)) {
            ObjFeed.push({ 'lat': lat, 'lng': lng });
        } else {
            console.log('exact match for lat lng');
        }
    }
     // this is for to keep only few objects in the list and remove other
    if (ObjFeed.length >= checkLengthInterval) {
        // calculating angle only if previous data point is available
        ObjFeed = ObjFeed.slice(-1 * checkLengthInterval); // remove all items in array except last two
        var point1 = ObjFeed[ObjFeed.length - checkLengthInterval];
        var point2 = ObjFeed[ObjFeed.length - 1];

        console.log('previous point1', point1);
        console.log('next point2', point2);

        var dLng = (point2.lng - point1.lng);
        var dLat = (point2.lat - point1.lat);

        dLng = dLng * 10000;
        dLat = dLat * 10000;

        var dlat_by_dlan = 0;

        try {
            dlat_by_dlan = dLng / dLat;
        } catch (err) {
            dlat_by_dlan = NaN;
            console.log('Exception: dLat == 0');
        }

        var angleDegreeBearing = 0, angleBearingRad = 0;
        angleBearingRad = Math.atan(dlat_by_dlan);
        angleDegreeBearing = angleBearingRad * 180 / Math.PI;

        if (dLat < 0 && dLng < 0) {
            angleDegreeBearing = angleDegreeBearing + 180;
        } else if (dLat < 0 && dLng > 0) {
            angleDegreeBearing = angleDegreeBearing + 180;
        } else if (dLat == 0 && dLng == 0) {
            angleDegreeBearing = prevVechicleAngle;
        } else if (dlat_by_dlan == NaN) {
            angleDegreeBearing = prevVechicleAngle;
        }

        console.log('angleDegreeBearing', angleDegreeBearing);

    } else {
        // setting up default angle to 0 if previous data point is not available to calculate actual anglle
        console.log('feedArray default angle 0');
        angleDegreeBearing = 0;
    }
    prevVechicleAngle = angleDegreeBearing;
    return angleDegreeBearing;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you require an accurate method on an ellipsoid of revolution (i.e. WGS 84), the [algorithms](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z) get really heavy. You may benefit from [**GeographicLib**](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/), which has been implemented in C/C++, Java, JavaScript, Python, Matlab/Octave, and others.

For the question, there is either a [**geodesic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid) or a [**rhumb line**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhumb_line) between the first and second point.

## Geodesic

A geodesic is the shortest path between two points on a curved surface. It is the most common interpretation of where a "user is heading" (from the question), since it is the shortest and most direct. An inverse geodesic calculation can be solved using [GeodSolve](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/GeodSolve.1.html). You can also use the [online interface](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/GeodSolve). This tool has the input/output:

> *lat1 lon1 lat2 lon2* → *azi1 azi2 s12*

Where *lat1 lon1* is the coordinate pair for the first point, and *lat2 lon2* is the coordinate pair for the second point. All units are in degrees (not radians). The result, *azi1* or α<sub>1</sub>, is the azimuth (a.k.a. bearing) from the start point, given in degrees clockwise from north. The second azimuth is at the second point, because the angle between the two points along a geodesic is not constant. And *s12* is the distance between the two points, in metres, with an accuracy of 15 nm.

## Rhumb line

A rhumb line connects two coordinate points with a constant azimuth (or bearing). 
An inverse rhumb line calculation can be solved using [RhumbSolve](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/RhumbSolve.1.html). You can also use the [online interface](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/RhumbSolve). This tool has the input/output:

> *lat1 lon1 lat2 lon2* → *azi12 s12*

These parameters are the same as GeodSolve, except that *azi12* is a constant angle between the points.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the calculations for the [Great Circle bearing](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Comment: Hi HPM, no I do not need Great circle bearing. Just need the angle :)

Comment: @praethorian -- two Latitude/Longitude points define (an arc of) a Great Circle, you'll have to explain what you mean by the angle between them.

Comment: @praethorian: I think you want the calculations for the Great Circle Bearing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
cos(say) = (cosd(90-lat(1))) * (cos(90-lat(2)))
         + (sin(90-lat(1))) * (sind(90-lat(2)) * (cosd(abs(Landa(2)-landa(1)))));
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who use C/C++, below is the tested code:

```
static const auto PI = 3.14159265358979323846, diameterOfEarthMeters = 6371.0 * 2 * 1000;

double degreeToRadian (double degree) { return (degree * PI / 180); };
double radianToDegree (double radian) { return (radian * 180 / PI); };

double CoordinatesToAngle (const double latitude1,
                           const double longitude1,
                           const double latitude2,
                           const double longitude2)
{
  const auto longitudeDifferenceRadians = degreeToRadian(longitude2 - longitude1);
  auto latitude1Radian = degreeToRadian(latitude1),
       latitude2Radian = degreeToRadian(latitude2);

  const auto x = std::cos(latitude1Radian) * std::sin(latitude2Radian) -
                 std::sin(latitude1Radian) * std::cos(latitude2Radian) *
                 std::cos(longitudeDifferenceRadians);
  const auto y = std::sin(longitudeDifferenceRadians) * std::cos(latitude2Radian);

  return radianToDegree(std::atan2(y, x));
}

double CoordinatesToMeters (const double latitude1,
                            const double longitude1,
                            const double latitude2,
                            const double longitude2)
{
  auto latitude1Radian = degreeToRadian(latitude1),
       longitude1Radian = degreeToRadian(longitude1),
       latitude2Radian = degreeToRadian(latitude2),
       longitude2Radian = degreeToRadian(longitude2);
  auto x = std::sin((latitude2Radian - latitude1Radian) / 2),
       y = std::sin((longitude2Radian - longitude1Radian) / 2);

  return diameterOfEarthMeters *
         std::asin(std::sqrt((x * x) +
                             (std::cos(latitude1Radian) * std::cos(latitude2Radian) * y * y)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone need `PHP` code for this functionality:

```
/**
 * Calculate angle between 2 given latLng
 * @param  float $lat1
 * @param  float $lat2
 * @param  float $lng1
 * @param  float $lng2
 * @return integer
 */
function angle($lat1, $lat2, $lng1, $lng2) {
    $dLon = $lng2 - $lng1;
    $y = sin($dLon) * cos($lat2);
    $x = cos($lat1) * sin($lat2) - sin($lat1) * cos($lat2) * cos($dLon);
    return 360 - ((rad2deg(atan2($y, $x)) + 360) % 360);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering **Nayanesh Gupte**'s answer and its comments. I've changed some part of the code and wrote it in `PHP`.

- **latitude** and **longitude** have been converted to **radians** inside the function.

Here is the function:

```
function angleFromCoordinate($lat1, $long1, $lat2, $long2) {

    $lat1 = deg2rad($lat1);
    $lat2 = deg2rad($lat2);
    $long1 = deg2rad($long1);
    $long2 = deg2rad($long2);

    $dLon = $long2 - $long1;

    $y = sin($dLon) * cos($lat2);
    $x = cos($lat1) * sin($lat2) - sin($lat1) * cos($lat2) * cos($dLon);

    $brng = atan2($y, $x);

    $brng = $brng * 180 / pi();
    $brng = fmod($brng + 360, 360);

    return $brng;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure its a rhumb line bearing NOT a great circle bearing as the
>   initial bearing changes according to distance

```
 double angle= Math.min((pbearingf-tbearingf) < 0 ? pbearingf-tbearingf+360:pbearingf-tbearingf, (tbearingf-pbearingf)<0?tbearingf-pbearingf+360:tbearingf-pbearingf);
```

Answer (score 0):

With javascript, just use [Turf](http://turfjs.org/docs/#bearing):

```
var point1 = turf.point([-75.343, 39.984]);
var point2 = turf.point([-75.534, 39.123]);

var bearing = turf.bearing(point1, point2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how calculated the bearing in Java using Math. In my case, I have lat-long in degrees so I converted them in radians before using them. If you have lat-long in radian you might wanna remove those four lines. I have also commented the formulas that I used to calculate the bearing.

```
    public float calculateBearing(float currentLat, float currentLon, float destinationLat, float destinationLon) {

    //if lat,lon are in degrees convert them to radians (in my case they are in degrees)
    currentLat = (float) Math.toRadians(currentLat);
    currentLon = (float) Math.toRadians(currentLon);
    destinationLat = (float) Math.toRadians(destinationLat);
    destinationLon = (float) Math.toRadians(destinationLon);

    // a -> current | b -> destination
    // ‘L’ be the longitude in radians,
    // ‘θ’ be latitude in radians,
    // ‘β‘ be Bearing.
    // ∆ be the difference (b - a)

    // ∆L = L b - L a
    // β = atan2(X,Y)
    // X = cos θb * sin ∆L
    // Y = cos θa * sin θb – sin θa * cos θb * cos ∆L
    
    double X, Y;
    X = Math.cos(destinationLat) * Math.sin(destinationLon - currentLon);
    Y = (Math.cos(currentLat) * Math.sin(destinationLat)) -
            (Math.sin(currentLat) * Math.cos(destinationLat) * Math.cos(destinationLon - currentLon));


    float radianBearing = (float) Math.atan2(X, Y);
    //converting bearing in radian to degrees
    return (float) Math.toDegrees(radianBearing );
}
```

I studied and followed the formulas provided here https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/. You can further read this for better understanding.

For testing, you can visit this https://www.igismap.com/map-tool/bearing-angle. It has a map where you can select your starting coordinates (A) and end coordinates (B) to get the Bearing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript version that actually works, taken from leaflet.geometryutil.js

```
function bearing (latlng1, latlng2) {
  const rad = Math.PI / 180
  const lat1 = latlng1.lat * rad
  const lat2 = latlng2.lat * rad
  const lon1 = latlng1.lng * rad
  const lon2 = latlng2.lng * rad
  const y = Math.sin(lon2 - lon1) * Math.cos(lat2)
  const x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) -
      Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lon2 - lon1)

  const bearing = ((Math.atan2(y, x) * 180 / Math.PI) + 360) % 360
  return bearing >= 180 ? bearing - 360 : bearing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun angleFromCoordinate(
    lat1: Double, long1: Double, lat2: Double,
    long2: Double
): Double {
    val dLon = long2 - long1
    val y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2)
    val x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - (sin(lat1)
            * cos(lat2) * cos(dLon))
    var brng = atan2(y, x)
    brng = Math.toDegrees(brng)
    brng = (brng + 360) % 360
    brng = 360 - brng 
    return brng
}
```

on kotlin

Answer (score 0):

The usual reference https://www.igismap.com/map-tool/bearing-angle gives negative values. But as per  https://youtu.be/mMrf1Wn6-XA?t=112 it should be counted clockwise from N.

```
    if bearing_angle < 0: #count it clockwise 
        # Normalize the bearing angle to a value between 0° and 360°
        bearing_angle = (bearing_angle + 360) % 360
```

That's the only change from @nbeuchats answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45424986/429476)

Updated answer;

```
def calculate_bearing_angle(point1, point2):
   
    Calculate the bearing angle between two points on the Earth's surface.
    
    Parameters:
    - point1: tuple of (latitude, longitude) for the first point.
    - point2: tuple of (latitude, longitude) for the second point.
    
    Returns:
    - bearing angle in degrees.
          
    """
    
    # Convert degrees to radians
    lat1 = math.radians(point1[0]) 
    lon1 = math.radians(point1[1]) 
    lat2 = math.radians(point2[0])
    lon2 = math.radians(point2[1])
    
    # Calculate the difference in longitudes
    delta_lon = lon2 - lon1
    
    # Calculate the bearing angle
    x = math.atan2(math.sin(delta_lon) * math.cos(lat2),
                   math.cos(lat1) * math.sin(lat2) - math.sin(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.cos(delta_lon))
    #log.debug(f"bearing angle in radians={x}")
    # Convert the bearing angle from radians to degrees
    bearing_angle = math.degrees(x)
    log.debug(f"bearing angle without normalisation={bearing_angle}")
    
    if bearing_angle < 0: #count it clockwise see  https://youtu.be/mMrf1Wn6-XA?t=112
        # Normalize the bearing angle to a value between 0° and 360°
        bearing_angle = (bearing_angle + 360) % 360
    return bearing_angle
```

Testing it

```
receiver_loc = (30.1225, -101.09655555555555)
transmitter_loc = (29.774166666666666, -101.16900000000001)
calculate_bearing_angle(receiver_loc,transmitter_loc)
```

output

```
190.2334434245182
```

Putting it here to test http://www.geomidpoint.com/destination/

we got the transmitter back

[image]

However if we use the value from https://www.igismap.com/map-tool/bearing-angle, it gives as -169.767 which does not work with the above tool (should be between (0 to 360)

[image]

So the code above seems right